# Dynamic bucketing in matrix visual in Power BI

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, analysis

So I have received a report with a smilar bucketing as show below in the dummy file attached. The report attached has a parameter which the user can change and according to that the bucket values in the matrix dynamically change to display minimum, average and maximum weight in that specific range.

The Weight Bridge table is a generated series from values 0-400 which is connected to the weight values in the "forecasting" table via a relationship.

The lowest weight value is 20 and the highest value is 400.  And the measures such as "min_weight", "max_weight" and "avg. weight" are created by referencing the values in the weight bridge along with the value selected in the parameter which deterines the bucket size.

The objective is to display the values at the top of the matrix in the form "0-50", "50-100", etc. instead of how it is displayed right now (as singular numbers "0", "50", etc.)

And this display should dynamically change as the parameter value is changed. So if it is set to 100 then it should display the buckets "0-100", "100-200", "200-300", "300-400".

Have tried a few things but cant figure it out as to display it like that we would have to change the data type of the column from numeric to string.

If anyone has any ideas that might work, I will really appreciate listening to it! Any input is welcome. Thanks a lot :)

Edit: Here is the link! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o77l9WeMbOZXHSk8KOwv8X8Mc-osPAaV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The best way to do this is generate a new table which is the Cartesian product of all combinations with columns in there for min and max as ints and a column for display as text data type. i.e. a completely different approach to the existing one.

Comment: Hey @DavidBacci could you please elaborate a bit on this? Do you have any guides or sources I could reference for this..?